# Dynamic SOQL, LIKE and Apostrophes

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

I want use an Aura component to perform a lookup on Accounts. For example I want to search for an Account named **O'Neills**.

The query is:

```
query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :value';
```

The value variable is passed to the controller and modified like so:

```
value = '%'+value+'%';
```

The documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) quite generally dictates that in dynamic SOQL I should also use:

```
value = String.escapeSingleQuotes(value);
```

However at runtime this appears to be evaluated by Database.query() as:

```
DEBUG: SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%O\'Neills%'
```

Which does not return the desired Account.

If we do not use String.escapeSingleQuotes(value) the query is evaluated as:

```
DEBUG: SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%O'Neills%'
```

This returns the desired Account.

Why is the ' being treated as a String literal (as opposed to part of the SOQL command), is it because it is a bound variable or because it is between the %s or is it because it is dynamic SOQL?

If the ' is being treated as a String literal, then surely there is no use in escaping single quotes and no risk of injection.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `:` to embed the value into the SOQL query, then it handles the escaping of special characters already.

If you build an actual string query and call it using `Database.query` then you would need to escape the single quotes.